# Clase module-info falta un super type

Tags: java, android, android-studio, test, test-ng

Estoy intentando hacer un caso de prueba con Appium en Android con algunas dependencias, pero una de ellas está causando este error:

> Illegal class file: Class module-info is missing a super type.

La dependencia que causa el problema es selenium-server-standalone-3.14
Las dependencias se incluyen como:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.14.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/java-client-6.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/java-client-6.1.0-javadoc.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar')
}
```

Estoy usando Android Studio 3.1.4.

Comment: Por lo que veo, creo selenium server no está hecho para android. Te recomiendo que mires esta web http://selendroid.io/, y utilices este otro jar.

Comment: Gracias, me ha dejado de dar el fallo.